# How to display multiple Lists of data with different properties

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an App that displays lists of data (Random selections from XML files, meant as Inspiration for Authors and Gamers)

When a category is selected, a "Datablock" is Instantiated, holding 50 randomly-created HashMaps, each describing an Entry in that Category. Each HashMap has Key/Value pairs relating to the Category chosen.
e.g. "Names" has keys: Forename and Surname. 
 "Treasures" has keys: Style, Item and Value, 
"Shop" has keys: Name, Descriptor, Type and Quality.
For each Key, a random Value is selected from the appropriate XML String_Array.

I am planning to display these in a RecyclerView, using an Adapter.
Is it possible to account for the varying amount and type of data in one Adapter, or should I conditionally call a different Adapter for each Category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `getItemViewType()` in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` and return a different `ViewHolder` based on the category of the item.

See also: [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)